# ggplot2 coord_flip() with geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to find a way to easily flip a plot annotated with geom_text(). The problem is that if I use coord_flip(), the labels are kind of not flipped.

A simple example, if I flip the plot like that:

```
df <- count(diamonds, cut)

ggplot(df, aes(x = cut, y = n, label = n)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
geom_text()
```

[image: ggplot not flipped]

by adding coord_flip(), I'm getting:
[image]

I know that this could be a desired behaviour in some cases but instead of that, I need the labels on the bars to stay aligned with the bars and look more like:

[image]

Is there any solution to that?

Comment: For readability, why not leave the text horizontal? You could do, for example, `ggplot(df, aes(x=cut, y=n, label=format(n, big.mark=","))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y=0.5*n), colour="white") +
  coord_flip()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `angle` aesthetic in `geom_text`, setting it to a fixed value.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = cut, y = n, label = n)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    geom_text(angle = 270) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]